# Find two employees having the same designation attribute - in SQL using self joins

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, self

Display records having the same designation as "Peter" using inner join

CONDITION : without directly using the designation of Peter in the WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: Can you provide some basic schema that you are working with? And also some test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess *technically* since you have `CONDITION : without directly using the designation of Peter in the WHERE CLAUSE.` you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1 
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.condition = t2.condition
    AND t2.name = 'Peter'
```

You have records matching Peter's without using "Peter" in a `WHERE` clause.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42baf/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (name varchar(10),  condition1 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO table1 (name, condition1)
SELECT 'Peter', 'c1' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul', 'c2' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mary', 'c1' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jay', 'c2' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SilentBob', 'c1' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bill', 'c1' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ted', 'c4' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rufus', 'c3' FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.condition1 = t2.condition1
  AND t2.name = 'Peter'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42baf/1/0)**:

```
|      NAME | CONDITION1 |  NAME | CONDITION1 |
|-----------|------------|-------|------------|
|     Peter |         c1 | Peter |         c1 |
|      Mary |         c1 | Peter |         c1 |
| SilentBob |         c1 | Peter |         c1 |
|      Bill |         c1 | Peter |         c1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
SELECT t2.Name, t2.Designation
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table1 t2
ON t1.Designation = t2.Designation
WHERE t1.Name = 'Peter'
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

It joins 2 tables (same table) on column `Designation`, filter the result for peter's designation and fetches first 2 rows only.

Comment: That works! Sadly I gave up and submitted the assignment moments before I saw your answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: nevermind.......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like table1 table1_name,attribute1,attribute2 and a table like table2_name, attribute1,..., and the name attribute would be like a id (unqiue through the table)

then

```
SELECT * FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1_name = table2_name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The inner join selects matching rows from both the tables. To understand the problem here, try the below SQL.

```
SELECT a.empname as a_empname, b.empname b_empname
FROM employee a 
JOIN employee b ON(a.designation = b.designation);
```

I have three employees Adam, Peter and Smith in my table and Peter and Smith have the same designation. The above query returned the below records:

```
a_empname   b_empname   
Adam        Adam
Smith       Smith
Peter       Smith
Smith       Peter
Peter       Peter
```

To get the required result if you select the column a.empname, you should filter on the column b.empname and vice versa.

so either of the following queries will work:

```
SELECT a.empname 
FROM employee a 
JOIN employee b ON(a.designation = b.designation)
WHERE b.empname="Peter";

SELECT b.empname 
FROM employee a 
JOIN employee b ON(a.designation = b.designation)
WHERE a.empname="Peter";
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this query gives result as per your criteria without where clouse please note that this query won't be good in terms of performance and I would not suggest you to use this on production.

```
Select * from employee e
Inner join designation d on (e.designationid= 
d.designationid ) and (e.designation =(select
distinct designation from employee e1 inner 
 join designation d1 on (e1.designationid 
=d1.designationid ) and e.name like 'peter' )
```

Comment: `e.designationid=e.designationid` <<< That could be a **very** expensive thing to do.

Comment: Actually it's a typo..

Comment: :-) I accidentally did that once on a table with 10M records joining to a table with 40M records. But my `JOIN` was on the 40M table back to itself. So a Cartesian Product on that many rows ended up being quite a few results.